# How to display different scores from a different category in just one page

Tags: java

I have 3 different categories (different frames each), those are connected by 'continue' button and the last frame is the 'done' button. After clicking the 'done' button, i want to display the result (by points) of each categories but whenever i click the done button the score of the last category is the same score as the two categories. Please help me I don't know how to do it.

Please note that I don't have codes in my 2 other frames to display the score in a result form

//here is my code in my last frame...

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
        "Select * from Questions where exam_category= 'Mathematics'");

    while (rs.next()) {
        Questions x = new Questions(
            rs.getString("Question_Id"), 
            rs.getString("Subject_Code"), 
            rs.getString("Exam_Category"),
            rs.getString("Question"), 
            rs.getString("Choice_A"), 
            rs.getString("Choice_B"),
            rs.getString("Choice_C"), 
            rs.getString("Choice_D"), 
            rs.getString("Answer"));
        list.add(x);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if(list.get(i).getAnswer().equals(userAnswer.get(i).toString())) {
            score++;
            System.out.print(score);
        }
    }

    new Result(score, list).setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(LogicalReasoning.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

//here is my code in my result form

```
public Result(int score, ArrayList<Questions> list) {
    initComponents();
    txtLogical.setText(String.valueOf(score + " out of " + list.size()));
    txtEnglish.setText(String.valueOf(score + " out of " + list.size()));
    txtMath.setText(String.valueOf(score + " out of " + list.size()));
}
```

Comment: If you want to display multiple different scores you need to store them in different variables. Perhaps you should the same for the list of questions. You could use an array of ints and array ot lists for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

`Result` should get all the scores from the 3 topics, so I would change it to:

```
public Result(int[] logicalResult, int[] englishResult, int[] mathResult) {
    initComponents();        
    txtLogical.setText(logicalResult[0] + " out of " + logicalResult[1]);
    txtEnglish.setText(englishResult[0] + " out of " + englishResult[1]);
    txtMath.setText(mathResult[0] + " out of " + mathResult[1]);
}
```

Each topic result is an `int[]` which has 2 values in it, the score and the number of questions for the topic.

Then to feed that, I would have a method that returns that little `int[]` for a given topic, so taking your current implementation, it would be something like this:

```
private int[] getScoreForTopic(String topic, List<Answer> userAnswers) {
    int score = 0;
    List<Questions> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        Connection con;
        // instantiate your connection

        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
           "Select * from Questions where exam_category= ?");
        stmt.setString(1, topic);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Questions x = new Questions(
                    rs.getString("Question_Id"),
                    rs.getString("Subject_Code"),
                    rs.getString("Exam_Category"),
                    rs.getString("Question"),
                    rs.getString("Choice_A"),
                    rs.getString("Choice_B"),
                    rs.getString("Choice_C"),
                    rs.getString("Choice_D"),
                    rs.getString("Answer"));
            list.add(x);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i).getAnswer().equals(userAnswer.get(i).toString())) {
                score++;
                System.out.print(score);
            }
        }


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // ...
    }

    return new int[] {score, list.size()};
}
```

Finally, you create the `Result` object this way:

```
int[] logicalResult = getScoreForTopic("Logical", userAnswerLogical);
int[] englishResult = getScoreForTopic("English", userAnswerEnglish);
int[] mathResult = getScoreForTopic("Mathematics", userAnswerMath);

new Result(logicalResult, englishResult, mathResult).setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
```

Comment: Thank for your help sir.. and how can i call the method getScoreForTopic? And btw I'm getting some error in here                                                                                         private int[] getScoreForTopic(String topic, List<Answer> userAnswers) {                                so intead of List<Answer> i make it List<String> is it okay sir?

Comment: the last part of my answer shows how to use `getScoreForTopic`. For `userAnswers` just use whatever list you have that holds the answers. If it is a `List<String>` then use that. I just put `List<Answer>` because I didn't know the type

Comment: omg i am really sorry sir if i am rather annoying but the first part of your answer shows NullPointerException `txtLogical.setText(String.valueOf(logicalResult[0] + " out of " + logicalResult[1]));`..should i change the 0 to i or something?

Comment: so it means that `logicalResult` is null.  You should get `logicalResult` from `getScoreForTopic`, and this should never return null

Comment: `txtLogical.setText(String.valueOf(getScoreForTopic("Logical", userAnswerLogical) + " out of " + logicalResult[1]));` is that code right of getting the `locicalResult` from `getScoreForTopic`?  I tried this one but NullPointerException shows again..

Comment: @catmer `txtLogical.setText(logicalResult[0] + " out of " + logicalResult[1]);` is correct or `int[] logicalResult = getScoreForTopic("Logical", userAnswerLogical); txtLogical.setText(logicalResult[0] + " out of " + logicalResult[1]);`

Comment: im not getting NullPointerException but the score of each categories does not count. What should i do?

Comment: use a debugger or add logs (`System.out.println`) to see what each line is doing, I gave you a general solution, now you need to debug it because I don't have all the information or database to fully test it.

Comment: can i send to you this program and please do check if all of what you've said matches of what I've do? it's difficult especially because i am a beginner..

Comment: If you can put it online somewhere I can have a look, git maybe